# How to create semantic search engine using OWL+mysql

Tags: mysql, rdf, owl, protege

I'm a beginner in Ontology but I searched a lot for my case and couldn't find a good answer.

my case is :
1- I've a big database which contains around 4 million records.
2- I've an owl file for the database schema.

now I need to establish a semantic search engine using the mapreduce, I read a lot in Jena and protege

I don't know how to solve this problem as my database is very big.

I tried to use Cellfie and Ontop plugins for Protege 5 , but Cellfie couldn't load my big excel file ( although I increased the Java heap), also Ontop just query my database without asserting the individuals of my classes !

so is there a way to create a semantic search engine with mysql database ? if the answer is no, how can I combine the data in the database with the owl file ????

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear what you're asking. You have a relation database and an ontology that describes the schema? Or do you have Excel files? I mean, an Excel file is for sure not a relational database (in my opinion at least). And what means "Semantic Search Engine"? What does it do in your opinion? And then, what is the relation to Map-Reduce? I mean, you used a lots of terms and buzz words, but I'm not sure if you know what you really need and want?

Comment: That said, the common way is either to do OBDA or you convert the relational data to RDF triples. The latter one can be done via R2RML mappings and a tool. Then you could load the data into a triple store. Still don't know why you need Map-Reduce? And clearly, "Semantic Search Engine" is a vague and broad term - whatever it is, implenting software systems is clearly out of scope for StackOverflow and considered "off-topic"

Comment: Thanks AKSW for your time and effort to get what I mean , about your questions:
- I've a database and also excel files for the tables 
- I need to convert the relational data to RDF triples , yes , how can I do that?
- after having the RDF triples , I can load it in TDB and indexing my data so in that case i'll have a semantic search engine.
- about mapreduce , i've million of records , so i'll use hadoop for indexing the rows

Comment: use any R2RML tool for conversion from relational DB to RDF. Indeed, you have to create the mappings. But even Ontop should be sufficient, you can materialize the triples using the CLI